# Can I take many cuttings from one stalk?

Tags: flowers

I want to take cuttings from impatiens new guinea. I was wondering if I can take many cuttings from the same stalk or does it have to be just the top part?
I understand that they should have some leaves on them but I was thinking maybe I could leave the lower leaves on the other parts of the stalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get lucky, but the recommended method is to use the tip of the stalk. Whatever you do, you need a few leaves on the cutting, because the plant needs leaves for photosynthesis in order to grow.

If you want a lot of cuttings from one plant, you can "prune" the tip of the stalks back to just above a leaf on the parent plant, and it will then grow several stems from the one you cut back. Then use the tip of each stem as a cutting.

Obviously this involves a bit of planning ahead, but "pinching out" the tips of the stems like this is a good idea anyway, because it will give you more flowers on a smaller "bushier" plant.